# How to change the default property of a class from main function in Dart?

Tags: class, oop, object, flutter, dart

> So basically what I'm trying to do is to change the default value of property for all the objects of the class.

In the image below:

[image]

When I replace **Person().new** value with **abc** it doesn't change. Moreover there is no error from the compiler!!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value to be the same across different instances of the same class, use the `static` keyword:

```
class Person {

  static var defaultName = 'Kshitij';

  String name;

  Person([this.name]){
    name ??= defaultName; // if name is null, use default name.
  }
}
```

Now you can change the default name to Agarwal by writing:

```
  Person.defaultName = 'Agarwal';
```